# PHP array cannot use key to get value

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this array:

```
Array ( ["id"] => 2015020052 ["gs"] => 5 ["ts"] => "THURSDAY 10/15" 
["tsc"] => "final" ["bs"] => "FINAL" ["bsc"] => "final" 
["atn"] => "Chicago" ["atv"] => "blackhawks" ["ats"] => "1" 
["atc"] => "" ["htn"] => "Washington" ["htv"] => "capitals" 
["hts"] => "4" ["htc"] => "winner" ["pl"] => true ["rl"] => true 
["vl"] => true ["gcl"] => true ["gcll"] => true ["ustv"] => "" 
["catv"] => "" )
```

I am trying to get particular values, like home team and away team and the scores, but I cannot get the values.

I am trying this:

```
echo "away team is ". $array['atv'];
```

But i just get 
away team is

What am i missing????

var_dump gives me this:

```
Array vs array(21) { [""id""]=> string(10) "2015020051" 
[""gs""]=> string(1) "5" [""ts""]=> string(16) ""THURSDAY 10/15"
[""tsc""]=> string(7) ""final"" [""bs""]=> string(7) ""FINAL"" 
[""bsc""]=> string(7) ""final"" [""atn""]=> string(8) ""Ottawa""
[""atv""]=> string(10) ""senators"" [""ats""]=> string(3) ""0"" 
[""atc""]=> string(2) """" [""htn""]=> string(12) ""Pittsburgh""
[""htv""]=> string(10) ""penguins"" [""hts""]=> string(3) ""2""
[""htc""]=> string(8) ""winner"" [""pl""]=> string(4) "true" 
[""rl""]=> string(4) "true" [""vl""]=> string(4) "true" 
[""gcl""]=> string(4) "true" [""gcll""]=> string(4) "true" 
[""ustv""]=> string(2) """" [""catv""]=> string(2) """" }
```

Comment: output this `var_dump($array);`

Comment: $array[0]->atv still give me blank.

Comment: Do I need to strip the quotes before setting the array keys/values?

Comment: @PatrickLewis probably. or access like `array['"atv"']`

Comment: That did work, but the value includes the quotes, so looks like i need to clean it up at the beginning and remove the exra ones.

Comment: since you pointed it out (to yourself:), post an answer here with whatever you did to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing a correct associative array, this must be like this:

```
<?php

$array = [
        'id' => 2015020052,
        'gs' => 5,
        'ts' => "THURSDAY 10/15",
        'tsc' => "final", 
        'bs' => "FINAL",
        'bsc' => "final",
        'atn' => "Chicago",
        ...
    ];
```

Now you can get the value:

```
echo "away team is ". $array['atv'];
```

Here is the [Demo](https://eval.in/452463)

Comment: he's not posting how he initialized the array, just the contents of a var_dump and probably a print_r

Comment: He is trying to get values from array, as he says: "I am trying to get particular values, like home team and away team and the scores, but I cannot get the values.". I did put this code,'cause if he can't get the values, it could be due to a bad array initialization.

Comment: see the comments on the post. his keys and values had `"` around them for some reason. He didn't actually post code, only the results of a print_r and a var_dump. Neither of those print commas. You're not wrong though

Comment: You are correct too, but if you check his answer, all it seems that it was a bad initialization. I think if we only give answer for patching things, the people that is asking will have all code wrong, in my personal opinion, I like to give complete answers.

Comment: Probably. it depends on how he was building his array. I'm all for giving complete answers but he didn't provide enough information to make that assumption. imo :)

Comment: I had to str_replace the double quotes with nulls and now it works with $array["atv"].  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  One step closer.

Comment: That's another problem, many people post here incomplete questions :( ... @PatrickLewis, we don't know what is the background of code, but the important thing is you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem.

Problem:

The array was retrieved in Database [saved as a JSON encoded variable].

I was not getting the array element by key like `$arr['key']`

Solution:

Tried everything, no success.

Lastly, tried [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

`$arr = json_decode(json_encode($arr), TRUE);`

Note that second parameter `TRUE` is very important. Otherwise, you will get object returned.

And it worked like charm.